# Extend subnet with dfl-800

Tags: networking, firewall, subnet, d-link

i have 2 locations which are connected with vpn over internet with 2 dfl-800 firewalls.

Address config in firewall:

Location 1 address 192.168.0.0/24. (no dhcp)

Location 2 address 192.168.5.0/24. (dhcp handled on sbs 2008)

I want to dissolve location 1 and bring all devices physically behind the firewall in location 2.

Is it sufficent to change address of location 2 to 192.168.0.0/21, remove vpn specific rules, and connect the devices from location 1?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it worked like described in the question. I also had to recreate dhcp range and adjust netmask to 255.255.248.0 for devices with static ip configuration.